# Copy one column into existing columns and keep name of existing columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data:

```
 structure(list(Name = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), `Data 2018-08` = c(4L, 
5L, 2L, 4L), `Data 2018-09` = c(5L, 4L, 5L, 4L), `Data 2018-10` = c(9L, 
4L, 4L, 2L), `Data 2018-11` = c(7L, 3L, 6L, 7L), `Data 2018-12` = 9:6, 
    `Data 2019-01` = c(5L, 9L, 7L, 2L), `Data 2019-02` = c(9L, 
    6L, 3L, 4L), `Data 2019-03` = c(8L, 7L, 4L, 6L), `Data 2019-04` = c(7L, 
    6L, 6L, 5L), `Data 2019-05` = c(6L, 8L, 7L, 7L), `Data 2019-06` = c(3L, 
    7L, 2L, 7L), `Data 2019-07` = c(5L, 8L, 7L, 2L), `Data 2019-08` = c(5L, 
    7L, 3L, 3L), `Data 2019-09` = c(7L, 4L, 5L, 4L), `Data 2019-10` = c(5L, 
    2L, 8L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L
))
```

How can I copy the values in column 09-2019 to all columns from 08-2018-08-2019 and keeping the columns' original name?

When I use mutate from the dplyr package, new columns are added instead of replacing the old values of the already existing columns.

Comment: why not simply use `df[,2:10] <- df[,15] ` ?

Comment: Thank you for the response. This is a very easy way to do it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you are asking, and you want to use `mutate`, this should work:

```r
library(dplyr)
df  %>% 
    mutate(across(`Data 2018-08`:`Data 2019-08`, ~ `Data 2019-09`))
```

Edit: changed to tidy evaluation using `~`.

Comment: When I try to run this code with my original data, the columns are still the same. Do you know why this could be?

Comment: @remo did you assign the value to `df`? e.g. `df <- df  %>% 
    mutate(across(\`Data 2018-08\`:\`Data 2019-08\`, ~ \`Data 2019-09\`))`

Comment: Yes, I did. Now it doesn't even work anymore with the code in your answer above. I have the dplyr open in the library. I also restarted R. What else could be the problem?

Comment: If it worked before, I have no idea why it would suddenly stop working. The code is correct and works for me. It's better to use column names than indexing as suggested in the comments, as it's more explicit and robust to changes in the data. You could try replacing `~ \`Data 2019-09\`` with `function(x) df$\`Data 2019-10\`` but this isn't quite as good, i.e. it will work for this but not if you start doing grouping operations.

Comment: So in my case I had to write: df  %>% 
  dplyr:: mutate( across((`Data 2018-08`: `Data 2019-08`), ~ `Data 2019-09`))

Comment: Ah OK that can happen if `mutate` is masked by another package. I'm surprised it persisted when you restarted R though.